# QString::number pad with zero if number is positive

Tags: string-formatting, padding, qstring

I'm trying to print out numbers with fixed alignment such that if the number is positive OR negative it will still be aligned. Basically if the number is negative nothing gets padded, but if the number is positive then it gets a single padding in the place of where the '+' symbol would go

Here's some code that explains my problem:

```
qDebug() << "current behaviour";
qDebug() << "Num:" << QString::number(-5);
qDebug() << "Num:" << QString::number(5);
qDebug() << "desired behaviour";
qDebug() << "Num:" << QString("-5");
qDebug() << "Num:" << QString(" 5");


qDebug() << "this works, but would like to avoid this much typing...";
int val = -5;
qDebug() << "Num:" << QString(val >= 0, ' ') + QString::number(val);
val = 5;
qDebug() << "Num:" << QString(val >= 0, ' ') + QString::number(val);
```

And here's the output:

[image]

I know QString::number() has a number of parameters to adjust precision, but I haven't been able to find the right parameters to do this easily.

**EDIT**

My original example was a poor one. So here is more information. The values will actually be of type `double` and I know their values will always be -10 < val < 10. I also only want to display one decimal place. So here's a more realistic example (also using `QString::arg()` this time)

```
qDebug() << "current output";
qDebug() << "num:" << QString("%1").arg( 5.532,4,'f',1,QChar('0'));
qDebug() << "num:" << QString("%1").arg(-5.532,4,'f',1,QChar('0'));
qDebug() << "num:" << QString("%1").arg( 0.532,4,'f',1,QChar('0'));
qDebug() << "num:" << QString("%1").arg(-0.532,4,'f',1,QChar('0'));
qDebug() << "desired output";
qDebug() << "num:" << QString(" 5.5");
qDebug() << "num:" << QString("-5.5");
qDebug() << "num:" << QString(" 0.5");
qDebug() << "num:" << QString("-0.5");
```

And here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Use `QString::arg()` http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-4

Comment: and what parameters would you use in `arg()`?

Comment: The first 2 parameters. The first is the integer. The second is the field width.

Comment: See edits. I tried using the field width option, but since I'm 'zero padding' it ends up filling that extra space with a zero...